# Animation in iOS - what format should graphics be?

Tags: ios, animation, graphics

I have written a specification for an iOS app that will include a character on the screen that guides the user through a series of steps. I've had images of the character drawn in Illustrator however they're currently flat drawings only.

In the final app I'd like the character to be animated with a more 3D appearance, similar to the Tommy Cat character seen in this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgLMdBh4-eQ

While I don't envisage the animation to be as extensive I'd like the character to make small gestures (hand waving, tail wagging) and facial expressions (happy, sad, etc)

I don't expect the app developer will also do the character animation so I need to know what format (type/dimensions) I should be requesting the animations to be created in so they will be suitable for inclusion in the finished app.

Longer term it would be useful if the same animations could also be used in an Android version of the app - not sure if the one format would be ok across both platforms.

Comment: Why don't you ask your developer?

Comment: I'm not ready to hire a developer yet so I'm trying to get a headstart on the graphical/animation requirements of the app

Comment: Then you should still ask the developer, before you hire him/her. Don't expect that all developers know all formats. Many programmers also have their own formats for animations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and straightforward thing to do is hire an animator and have them export a Quicktime video that makes use of the lossless Animation codec. Typically, a 24BPP video is used. But, if you need an alpha channel then have the artist export a 32BPP video with an alpha channel included. Your developer will then have to deal with importing the video content, the most simple means would be to export a series of PNG images (this is not optimal but works just fine for a prototype).